# iOS: Releasing app for third party testing

Tags: ios, testflight

I have developed an iOS app. I want to give it for third party testing. What should i choose scheme when creating build for third party testing, Debug or Release? Third party testing device UDID is included in the provisioning profile.
If I use TestFlight for OTA installation, will the UDID to be included still? (or) TestFlight app doesn't need any UDID included in the build?

Please advise!

Thank you!

Comment: UDID is needed until the application is using Developer certificate. Any third party build Creation you has to give the UDIDS .

Comment: Don't use TestFlight, is shutting down, use HockeySDK or something else.

Comment: @NSElvis Link, reference, or GTFO

Comment: TestFlight's parent company was purchased by Apple weeks ago. It's highly unlikely they will keep TestFlight alive. It will be shut down any day now based on previous purchases Apple has made.

Comment: That's just speculation and an opinion.

Comment: @Abizern not speculation or opinion, confirmed by an Apple press release. Apple has never purchased a developer tool without shutting it down either immediately or some months later. Sometimes they relaunch it as part of their own developer tool suite, under a new name. As far as I know AuthenTec is the only company Apple has ever purchased without subsequently shutting it down.

Comment: As I said earlier, link to the press release; or this is still just speculation.

Comment: @Abizern: Apple doesn't have press releases for acquiring minor companies.

Comment: We know that Apple acquired the holding company. The bit that is speculation is the statement that Apple will shut TestFlight down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive your app, which will be a release build by default as far as I know. Doesn't really matter what the build type is, then in the archive manager click "distribute" and "save for enterprise or ad-hoc deployment", and select a provisioning profile for the app that has your beta tester's device IDs embedded in it, only those devices will be able to run the app.

This will create a file with the profile built in. Users can install it on their phone using three methods:

- add it to their iTunes library and sync the phone using USB
- use the "iPhone Configuration Utility", which is a free download for windows/mac from Apple's website, and doesn't require iTunes and all the baggage that brings along with it
- upload the file to a website and also upload an XML file pointing to the download URL and also a PNG image, display name, and a few other things. Get the iOS device to visit the XML file's URL with `itms-services://` as the protocol. Any means to open the URL is fine, email, website link, SMS message, whatever.

Test Flight uses the third approach. But you can easily set it up yourself.

Extensive documentation for all three approaches is available at http://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

(Seems like I can't comment yet). In response to the comments posted to the original question:

TestFlight, part of Burstly, is now Apple propery, as mentioned in this rumor
http://www.macrumors.com/2014/02/21/apple-may-acquire-testflight/

and later confirmed by Apple.
http://recode.net/2014/02/21/apple-confirms-burstly-buy/

As mentioned by someone, Apple uses shuts down their acquisitions and hence it may not be a very good idea to start using it now.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever method you use you'll need to build the app with a provisioning profile that includes your tester's device UDID.

I suggest using a Release build, so they are actually going to be testing the same version you are planning on releasing.